# How do I erase the first 7 columns plus the last, the 9th, only leaving the 8th column in a 3d vector like vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>?

Tags: c++

How do I erase the first 7 columns plus the last, the 9th, only leaving the 8th column in a 3d vector like `vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>`?

This works fine:

```
for (vector<vector<pair<int,int> > >::iterator it = allPathCoordinates.begin();
     it != allPathCoordinates.end();
     it += 1)
{
  v_temp = *it;
  for(vector<pair<int,int> >::iterator it2 = v_temp.begin();
      it2 != v_temp.end();
      ++it2)
  {
    apair = *it2;
    openPoints[apair.first][apair.second] = 0;
    closedPoints[apair.first][apair.second] = 1;
    allObstacles[apair.first][apair.second] = Wall;
    point[apair.first][apair.second] = Purple;
  }
}
cout << "allPathCoordinates.size():"
     << allPathCoordinates.size() << endl; // 79512
cout << "sizeof(allPathCoordinates):"
     << sizeof(allPathCoordinates) << endl; //24

vector< vector<pair<int,int> > >::size_type sz;
sz = allPathCoordinates.capacity();
cout <<  "capacity: "  <<  sz  <<  '\n';

allPathCoordinates.erase(allPathCoordinates.begin(),
                         allPathCoordinates.begin()+7);
cout << "allPathCoordinates.size():"
     << allPathCoordinates.size() << endl;
cout << "sizeof(allPathCoordinates):"
     << sizeof(allPathCoordinates) << endl;

sz=allPathCoordinates.capacity();
cout<< "capacity: " << sz << '\n';
```

Output:

```
allPathCoordinates.size():79512
sizeof(allPathCoordinates):24
capacity: 131072
allPathCoordinates.size():79505
sizeof(allPathCoordinates):24
capacity: 131072
```

As can be seen I have only reduced the number of elements with 
7. Not what I wanted. I want to reduce the number of columns with 8 out of the totally 9.
Hello mindriot and Bob
Thanks for your answer about “only copy that column”. Thing is that IO have tried that with memcpy, assign, copy_n, and copy, to no avail the last two weeks by now. If you have an idea please use my code above to show me how to do it.

To you “mindriot” I want to describe my problem like this:
“Look upon allPathCoordinates(vector > >  allPathCoordinates;) as a dynamic 3d array with 9 colums an unknown number of rows with different amount of integer pairs. What I want to keep is the 8th column intact with its unknown amount of integer pairs as the 3rd dimension.
That should be understood as if I'm not primarily interested in the elements i.e. the single first or second integer value in a pair. When having the 8th column extracted ( with memcpy, assign, copy_n, copy or some other better way) , I will iterate it to get the integer pairs (coordinates) for further use in a point() function like point[first][second]=Yellow;
Thanks for your interested.
Bo

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean you want to erase all elements from `allPathCoordinates` except for element 8?

Comment: Can't you only copy that column?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, what you need is to call [`std::vector::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) after `erase`.

We may also disagree on what a "column" of a `vector` is. Let me explain with a minimal program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;
using std::pair;

using thing = vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>;

void print ( thing &a ) {
    for ( auto && row : a ) {
        for ( auto && col : row ) {
            cout << std::setw(6) << col.first << ','
                 << std::setw(3) << col.second;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << "\nouter vector size: " << a.size()
         << " capacity: " << a.capacity() << '\n';
    cout << "inner vector size: " << a[0].size()
         << " capacity: " << a[0].capacity() << "\n\n";
}

int main() {
    thing a = {
        {  {1,  2},  {3,  4},  {5,  6} },   // <- that's row 0: a[0]
        {  {7,  9}, {10, 11}, {12, 13} },
        { {14, 15}, {16, 17}, {18, 19} },
        { {20, 21}, {22, 23}, {24, 25} }
    };  // ^^^^^^ 
        // This is a column, all the pairs a[i][0] for 0 <= i < N

    print(a);

    // erase the second row
    a.erase(a.begin() + 1);
    a.shrink_to_fit();

    print(a);

    // erase the second column
    for ( auto && row : a ) {
        row.erase(row.begin() + 1);
        row.shrink_to_fit();
    }

    print(a);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
     1,  2     3,  4     5,  6
     7,  9    10, 11    12, 13
    14, 15    16, 17    18, 19
    20, 21    22, 23    24, 25

outer vector size: 4 capacity: 4
inner vector size: 3 capacity: 3

     1,  2     3,  4     5,  6
    14, 15    16, 17    18, 19
    20, 21    22, 23    24, 25

outer vector size: 3 capacity: 3
inner vector size: 3 capacity: 3

     1,  2     5,  6
    14, 15    18, 19
    20, 21    24, 25

outer vector size: 3 capacity: 3
inner vector size: 2 capacity: 2
```

Comment: thanks for the pointing at the right direction, but I need help to understand why putting allPathCoordinates instead of your "thing" give this output:{ 442, 288}  { 441, 288}  { 440, 288}  { 442, 263}  { 441, 263}  { 440, 263}  { 442, 238}  { 441, 238}  { 440, 238}

Comment: thanks for  pointing me in the right direction. My comment have to many characters to fit, so can you please tell me how to reach you with a full comment. You reach me at bo.nystedt@sfr.fr.

Comment: @BoNystedt you are welcome. It would be a good idea to edit your question adding your initial data (at least the most significant ones) and the outputs you obtain and expect.